# How data stores in Database?

Tags: oracle

I've one doubt, it could be very lame, so please bear with me.

How and where database store its data ?

Online says

> This default option creates database files that are managed by the file system of your operating system. You can specify the directory path where database files are to be stored. Oracle Database can create and manage the actual files.

But file's data is actually in disk. No?

Is it a disk where it writes its data or something else is being performed?

Can anyone help me understand how it works?

Comment: Data is usually stored in files, on disks.

Answer (score 1):

here's a bit of light reading on Oracle physical storage structures.  Try not to get too excited.  It's a thrilling read :)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/physical.htm#CNCPT1389

Answer (score 1):

You're probably finding Oracle's documentation confusing because they give you a few different ways to manage storage.  It's *always* on disk, but its a question of *how* it's on disk.  You can do anything from having Oracle use raw partitions on a disk (bypassing the OS filesystem) to using data files on a filesystem.  It's partly a question of performance vs. convenience and partly that Oracle has been around a very long time.